# Byte serialization

Tags: c#, serialization, arrays, binaryformatter

I recently had a discussion with a colleague about serialization of byte data over a network.
He used the `BinaryFormatter` class to "unparse" the byte data I was sending to him. This did not work and he obviously had *exceptional*... exceptions. `Binaryformatter` could not "unparse" the data correctly since my data was simply a byte array.

His motivation for `BinaryFormatter` was platform independence. I am not persuaded of such a stance. When we both used `BinaryReader` or `BinaryWriter`, things worked well in code land.

What is the use therefore of `BinaryFormatter` and should I look at using it in each scenario wherever I need to send bytes over the wire?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Definitely, if you have your data as `byte[]`, `BinaryFormatter` is not a wise thing to use. You just write the data out to the wire. However, if you have a set of objects and want to serialize them to a stream, `BinaryFormatter` is much easier to use than manually writing each field of each type by hand. The purpose of `BinaryFormatter` or any serializer/deserializer scheme in general is to provide a way to persist an object graph (possibly complex) as a sequence of bytes.

Answer (score 2):

It sounds to me like you might want to look at something like "protocol buffers", which (unlike `BinaryFormatter`) is a high-performance, low-bandwidth, [portable/cross-platform](http://code.google.com/p/protobuf/wiki/ThirdPartyAddOns), version-tolerant binary serialization format (wow, that's a mouthful).

Fortunately, there are versions in .NET, such as [protobuf-net](http://code.google.com/p/protobuf-net/).

(disclosure: I'm the author, but it is free; I'm not trying to sell you anything - just save you a lot of time and pain)

`BinaryFormatter` is very... brittle; it is .NET specific and has relatively poor version tolerance. The only time I use it is behind the scenes for communicating between `AppDomain`s on the same machine. Otherwise, I'd look at contract-based serializers, such as `XmlSerializer`, `DataContractSerializer`, or protobuf-net.